# Matrix decompositions as monoid isomorphisms. Ever considered before?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, semigroups-and-monoids

I've noticed some correspondences between some matrix decompositions and monoid isomorphisms (always to some free commutative monoid), in addition to the one I asked about in a [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408148/the-matrix-direct-sum-monoid-modulo-unitary-equivalence):

1. Given a $*$-ring $R$, let $H(R,*)$ denote the set of Hermitian matrices over $R$ of all possible dimensions. We can make $H(R,*)$ into a monoid using the direct sum operation (denoted $\oplus$). Let $\sim_\text{US}$ be the equivalence relation denoting unitary similarity; in other words, we have that $A \sim_\text{US} B$ if there exists a unitary matrix $U$ such that $A = UBU^*$. Consider the monoid $H(R,*)/{\sim_\text{US}}$, and observe that the monoid is commutative.
2. Given a ring $R$, let $J(R)$ denote the set of square matrices of all possible dimensions over $R$. We can make $J(R)$ into a monoid using the direct sum operation (denoted $\oplus$). Let $\sim_\text S$ be the equivalence relation denoting matrix similarity; in other words, we have that $A \sim_\text S B$ if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A = PBP^{-1}$. Consider the monoid $J(R)/{\sim_\text S}$, and observe that the monoid is commutative.

Define $*:R \oplus R \to R \oplus R$, where $R$ is a ring (but not necessarily a $*$-ring), and $\oplus$ in this case denotes direct sum of rings, by $(x,y)^* = (y,x)$. We have that $H(R \oplus R,*)/{\sim_\text{US}} \cong J(R)/{\sim_\text S}$.

In the following, a *free commutative monoid* is always a monoid whose elements are all possible finite multisets whose elements belong to some ambient set. The elements of the ambient set are the *generators* of the monoid.

An isomorphism between $H(R,*)/{\sim_\text{US}}$ and a free commutative monoid is a *spectral theorem* over the $*$-ring $R$. And an isomorphism between $J(R)/{\sim_\text S}$ and a free commutative monoid is a *Jordan decomposition* for the ring $R$. Such isomorphisms appear to exist for many isolated rings, and in fact I've yet to see a ring for which these isomorphisms don't exist.

In the previous question, I defined $M(R,*)/{\sim_\text{UE}}$ in order to generalise the Singular Value Decomposition. The above two monoids are motivated here in a similar way.

Has this been studied in the literature to this degree of generality and for general rings?

[edit]

Category-theoretical insights: Observe that $H$, $J$, $M$ and their respective quotients are all functors from the category of $*$-rings to the category of monoids. Also, observe that the isomorphism $H(R \oplus R,*)/{\sim_\text{US}} \cong J(R)/{\sim_\text S}$ is *natural* in $R$. Observe also that the mapping $M \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0 & M^* \\ M & 0\end{pmatrix}$, which occurs in numerical linear algebra when computing the SVD, is a natural transformation from $M(R,*)/{\sim_\text{UE}}$ to $H(R,*)/{\sim_\text{US}}$.

[edit 2]

A paper I've produced on this topic: [Towards a Singular Value Decomposition and spectral theory for all rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.10247). In the paper, I've replaced $H$, $J$ and $M$ with other notation (unless there are typos where the old notation annoyingly persists).

Comment: I found your $R \oplus R$ example confusing, because I thought for a moment that $R$ itself was a $*$-ring; it may be worth mentioning explicitly that this is not assumed.  Then you referred to $H(R, *)$, but it seemed to be $H(R \oplus R, *)$; I edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks. Hopefully I've made it a bit clearer now.

Comment: Not an expert, but I think algebraic K-theory goes in this approximate direction.