# For every ring R, is there a block-diagonal canonical form for a square matrix over R?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, modules

This question asks whether there exists an analogue of the Jordan decomposition for an arbitrary ring $R$. This analogue is not necessarily the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition, which is unnecessarily strong. This follows from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408349/matrix-decompositions-as-monoid-isomorphisms-ever-considered-before), but you don't need to read it.

Given a ring $R$, let $J(R)$ be the monoid whose elements are all square matrices over $R$, and where the monoid operation is $\oplus$ denoting direct sum of matrices. Let $A { \sim_\text{S}} B$ mean that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1} = B$. Is the monoid $J(R)/{ \sim_\text{S}}$ *always a free abelian monoid*?

For perfect fields, the answer is yes by the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition. What about for every ring? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: This will be true if R is Artinian

Comment: I'm assuming in my comment R is commutative but I'm not sure it is necessary.  If R is commutative Artinian you are looking at indecomposable R[x] modules with a bounded length and can use Krull-Schmidt

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks. That's very helpful. I'm not assuming that $R$ is commutative because I know that $J(\mathbb H)/{\sim_{\text S}}$ is free abelian where $\mathbb H$ is the quaternions.

Comment: It should be true for R Artinian in general.

Comment: But I am not immediately sure how to phrase things in a module theory way. You basically want to make a category with objects pairs (V,A) with A is an nxn matrix over R and V an A-invariant submodule and show this is a krull schmidt category when R is artinian, which seems ok to me.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg How did you immediately know that it was true in the Artinian case? What references should I read?

Comment: I know it's quite a while since I asked this question.

Comment: I’m no longer so sure.  The endomorphism rings for this category are artinian and hence semiperfect  but I am no longer certain idempotents split.   Projectives with endomorphisms seems clear and now I need to convince myself it is enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is equivalent to whether the category $\mathcal{E}$ of pairs $(V,f)$ consisting of a finitely generated free (right) $R$-module and an endomorphism $f$ of $V$ is a *Krull-Schmidt category*, i.e., an additive category where every object decomposes as a direct sum of finitely many indecomposable objects and the decomposition is unique up to isomorphism and reordering. (The category $\cal E$ is also equivalent to the category of right $R[t]$-modules which are f.g. free $R$-modules, and it is rarely Krull-Schmidt, but I won't use this point of view.)

Here is one possible counterexample, phrased using the category $\mathcal{E}$ of pairs $(V,f)$ above: Take $R$ to be a Dedekind domain admitting a non-free rank-$1$ projective module $L$ such that $L\oplus L\cong R\oplus R$ (equivalently, $L$ represents an element of order $2$ in the Picard group of $R$). Let $f_L : L^2\to L^2$ be defined by $f_L(x,y)=(0,x)$, and define $f_R:R^2\to R^2$ similarly. The isomorphism $L\oplus L\cong R\oplus R$ gives rise to an isomorphism
$$(L^2,f_L)\oplus (L^2,f_L) \cong (R^2,f_R)\oplus (R^2,f_R)$$
in $\cal E$.
One readily checks that ${\rm  End}_{\cal E}(L^2,f_L)\cong R[\epsilon|\epsilon^2=0]$ and ${\rm  End}_{\cal E}(R^2,f_R)\cong R[\epsilon|\epsilon^2=0]$, so the endomorphism rings of $(L^2,f_L)$ and $(R^2,f_R)$ contain no nontrivial idempotents. This means that these objects are indecomposable in $\cal E$. On the other hand, $(L^2,f_L)\ncong (R^2,f_R)$ because $\ker f_L\cong L\ncong R\cong \ker f_R$. Consequently, the monoid $(\cal E/\cong, \oplus)$ (which is isomorphic to $(J(R)/\sim, \oplus)$ in your question) is not a free abelian monoid (because $2x=2y$ implies $x=y$ in a free abelian monoid).

One the other hand, a sufficient (but not necessary) condition for the category $\cal E$ to be Krull-Schmidt is that the endomorphism ring of every object $(V,f)$, i.e., the centralizer of $f$ in ${\rm End}_R(V)\cong {\rm M}_n(R)$, is a *semiperfect ring*.

For example, if $R$ is commutative and aritinian as in Benjamin Steinberg's comment, then  ${\rm End}_{\cal E}(V,f)$ will be an $R$-subalgebra of ${\rm End}_R(V)$, hence artinian, and in particular semiperfect.

The semiperfectness ${\rm End}_{\cal E}(V,f)$ for all f.g. free $V$ is actually true even if $R$ is non-commutative one-sided artinian, and even if $R$ is just *semiprimary*. This appears implicitly in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.2124.pdf) of mine (page 20 & Thm. 8.3(iii) & Remark 2.9).
When $R$ is commutative noetherian and local, one can use a [theorem of Azumaya](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-2/issue-none/On-maximally-central-algebras/nmj/1118764746.full) (Theorem 22) and a little work to show that this property is equivalent to $R$ being henselian.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of such an $L$ and $R$? Thanks

Comment: @ogogmad Take $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $L=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$, for instance. One has $L\cdot L=2R$. This is the simplest example I know.

Comment: How did you know that all this was true?

Comment: I know it's quite a while since I asked this question.

Comment: For semiperfect rings, Wikipedia only says that the category of f.g. projective modules is Krull-Schmidt. But projective modules aren't necessarily free modules. I'm wondering how you go from one to the other.

Comment: Sorry if this is rude. You can tell me if you're busy.

Comment: the answer contains references - did you try to consult them?

Comment: @wlad It is fine that you are asking. From your comments I understand that you are asking about the sufficient conditions for $\mathcal{E}$ to be Krull-Schmidt. You can get this by combining the Krull-Schmidt Theorem for additive categories in Bass' "Algebraic K-Theory", Thm.I.3.6 and the characterization of semiperfect rings in Rowen's "Ring Theory", vol. I, Prp.2.7.20. Actually, Sections 2.7, 2.8, 2.9 in the latter source contain many facts about semiperfect rings and projective modules.